# Show/hide div from separate links _ multiple boxes issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have managed to toggle a div with different links. But when i'm trying to make more boxes which the same it doesn't work anymore.

Imagine I have like 10 entries - all separated divs 'entry'

```
  <div class="entry" id="1">
```

where i want to separately hide and show content with multiple links.

My Question is, I'm trying to fix this since 5 hours, but which one div entry its working, with more than one it is not working.

I tried to use

```
$(".entry").each(function() {
```

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".entry").each(function() {
    var b4c = $('.lower_menu').html(); // content of box 4 so that we cn refer to it later
    $(".menu1,.menu2,.menu3").click(function() {
      var active_content = $(".lower_menu").data('content');
      var cls = $(this).attr('class');
      if (active_content == '') {
        $(".lower_menu").html($("." + cls + '_CONTENT').html())
        $(".lower_menu").data('content', cls);
      } else {
        if (active_content == cls) {
          $('.lower_menu').html(b4c).data('content', '');
        } else {
          $(".lower_menu").html($("." + cls + '_CONTENT').html())
          $(".lower_menu").data('content', cls);
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.menu1 {height:40px; background-color:red;}
.menu2 {height:40px; background-color:green;}
.menu3 {height:40px; background-color:blue;}

.menu1_CONTENT {display:none; background-color:red;}
.menu2_CONTENT {display:none; background-color:green;}
.menu3_CONTENT {display:none; background-color:blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="entry">
  <div class="menu1">
    <span id="arrow_prod" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down arrow"></span> Heading 1
  </div>
  <div class="menu2">BOX 2</div>
  <div class="menu3">BOX 3</div>

  <!-- data-content is to check do we have content or which boxes's content do we hv now -->
  <div class="lower_menu" data-content=""></div>
  <div class="menu1_CONTENT">CONTENT FOR BOX 1</div>
  <div class="menu2_CONTENT">CONTENT FOR BOX 2</div>
  <div class="menu3_CONTENT">CONTENT FOR BOX 3</div>
</div>

<div class="entry">
  <div class="menu1">BOX 1</div>
  <div class="menu2">BOX 2</div>
  <div class="menu3">BOX 3</div>

  <!-- data-content is to check do we have content or which boxes's content do we hv now -->
  <div class="lower_menu" data-content=""></div>

  <div class="menu1_CONTENT">CONTENT FOR BOX 1</div>
  <div class="menu2_CONTENT">CONTENT FOR BOX 2</div>
  <div class="menu3_CONTENT">CONTENT FOR BOX 3</div>
</div>
```

... and a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8u1wxw01/6/)

Comment: first of all ID can't start with number

Comment: is there no solution?

Comment: yep i guess we found a bug!

Answer (score 0):

it's a official bug of the jquery! We found one guys ! YEEEHAA